# Can I use SQL Server database with Apache Mahout?

Tags: sql-server, mahout

I chose to use Apache Mahout as my recommendation engine but at the same time due to some reasons it would be easier if I could store my data in a SQL Server db. Can mahout be connected with SQL Server without any problems ?

The documentation says that it can be connected with other db engines through JDB driver but I see all articles , books using mysql and also the data model supported are for mysql only.

Answer (score 0):

How to convert MySQL to SQL Server databases:

- SQL Import/Export Wizard through ODBC (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2205/mysql-to-sql-server-data-migration/)
- SQL Server Migration Assistant (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313125(v=sql.110).aspx)

Here is the JDBC driver for SQL server:

- JDBC Driver for SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx
- Changing DB input format/driver in Hadoop cluster: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/

There are also numerous example of using Mahout with an Azure Hadoop Cluster via HDInsight:

- http://bluewatersql.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/installing-mahout-for-hdinsight-on-windows-server/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620717/Building-A-Recommendation-Engine-Machine-Learning

Comment: The question isn't about using Mahout with Hadoop or HDinsight , it is about using it with a non-hadoop db which is SQL Server like mysql is used

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding - your situation seems possible but is beyond my experience. It is definitely poorly documented and may require lite customization through the GenericJDBCDataModel if is could even work. I added a few ways to convert mysql to sql server databases.

Answer (score 0):

I have just started my experiments with Mahout. I managed to run some book examples after replacing the in-memory data models with `SQL92JDBCDataModel` or `SQL92BooleanPrefJDBCDataModel` shipped with Mahout 0.9.

I passed an instance of `SQLServerDataSource` to constructors of those data models. This class is included into the [Microsoft JDBC Drivers for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774) package (I used the version 4.1)

However, the `SQL92JDBCDataModel` documentaton states that it is "not optimized for performance".